# Need to find an equation that will not allow user input to exceed 100 if user enters 90 for scoreEarned and 20 for scoreShift output will still be 100

Tags: python

I'm stuck on the elif statement I don't know how I would be able to have the input for example scoreEarned = 90 and scoreShift =20  which equals 110 just be a 100 as a max for the output. Like the max score that can be obtained is 100 but if the user got extra points over the 100, how could it still just return 100 as the maximum score?

```
#Message display description
print("This program reads exam/homework scores and reports your overall course grade.")

#Space
print()

#Title for Midterm 1
print("Midterm 1:")

#funtion that asks user for input to use
def totalPoint():

    #Asking user for weight of assignment
    weight = int(input("Weight (0-100)? "))

    #Asking user for score earned on assignment, max score is 100
    scoreEarned = int(input("Score earned? "))

    #variable for bottom half of fraction
    outOf = 100

    #prompting user to input 1 for yes and 2 for no
    yesOrNo = int(input("Were scores shifted (1=yes, 2=no)? "))

    #if statement for if there is a score shift
    if(yesOrNo == 1):

        #prompt user for shift amount
        scoreShift = int(input("Shift amount? "))

        #if statement that will check user input
        if(scoreShift > 0 and scoreShift + scoreEarned <= 100):
            
            #add score earned and score shift
            newTotalPoint = scoreEarned + scoreShift

            #display new total points
            print("Total points = ",newTotalPoint,"/",outOf)

        #elif statement if the combined total of the score shift and earned are more than 100
        elif(scoreShift > 0 and scoreShift + scoreEarned > 100):

            #Need to have a maximum of 100 for total points including the shift
            print("This is where I am stuck.")

    #else there is no shift score
    else:

        #Print the  score earned out of 100
        print("Total points = ",scoreEarned,"/",outOf)


totalPoint()
```

Comment: Take a look at the `min()` and `max()` functions, one of them could be used to accomplish this. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/max-min-python/

Comment: @PCM `min` and `max` works for any type that can be compared, not to mention that every instance of `input` is immediately cast to an `int`. However, as pointed out in the answers, the detection for a score shifted beyond 100 is already done and the answer can just be set to 100. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

Comment: @PCM That is verifiably false. Please read the documentation I linked and/or test it for yourself. That or provide evidence for your claims.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237654/discussion-between-andrew-harelson-and-pcm).

Answer (score 4):

Just put `print(100)`.
Like this:

```py
elif(scoreShift > 0 and scoreShift + scoreEarned > 100):
     #Need to have a maximum of 100 for total points including the shift
     print("Total points = 100")
```

Comment: You can simplify it as - `print("Total points = 100")`

Comment: Lol that is an answer. 

Answer (score 2):

Another more consise/pythonic way to accomplish this is to use the python built-in `min()` function as follows

```
scoreEarned = min(100, scoreEarned + scoreShift)
print("Total points = ",scoreEarned,"/",outOf)
```

`min` will return the smaller value of the two parameters passed to it. If `scoreEarned + scoreShift` is greater than your cap value of 100, `min` will return 100, otherwise it will return the original sum.

Comment: Thanks for the great explaination! I was think about this but didnt have a clue on how to use it. Besides using basic int numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `print("This is where I am stuck.")` with the logical output at this stage that matters `print("You exceeded the maximum score and will receive 100 points ")`

This is what I deduced from your question. That's what you want to do, right?